# Instagram php laravel access token

Tags: php, laravel, instagram

I was able to get the code from instagram api. The next step is to post the client_id, client_secret, grant_type, redirect_uri and code to https://api.instagram.com/oauth/access_token as shown below.

The instagram API says that "you simply have to POST this code, along with some app identification parameters, to our access_token endpoint."

```
 curl -F 'client_id=CLIENT_ID' \
    -F 'client_secret=CLIENT_SECRET' \
    -F 'grant_type=authorization_code' \
    -F 'redirect_uri=AUTHORIZATION_REDIRECT_URI' \
    -F 'code=CODE' \
    https://api.instagram.com/oauth/access_token
```

How can I do this in my laravel controller or php script? How do I put all these information as a variable and post it to the uri to get back the json object? Thank you

Comment: install guzzle for making curl request for example, then add redirect url in you routes\controller.

Answer (score -1):

using [`ssh`](https://laravel.com/docs/4.2/ssh) task runner

```
$commands = ["curl -F 'client_id=CLIENT_ID' \
    -F 'client_secret=CLIENT_SECRET' \
    -F 'grant_type=authorization_code' \
    -F 'redirect_uri=AUTHORIZATION_REDIRECT_URI' \
    -F 'code=CODE' \
    https://api.instagram.com/oauth/access_token"]

//       your command, the output of the command
SSH::run($commands   , function($line)
{
    echo $line.PHP_EOL;
});
```

**OR** simply using both php internal functions [exec](http://php.net/shell_exec), [shell_exec](http://php.net/exec) or [system](http://php.net/system)

---

Another approach -*in case of you want to keep away of shell commands*- is by using [`guzzle`](https://packagist.org/packages/guzzlehttp/guzzle) package or internal php [`cURL`](http://php.net/curl) library

Comment: I would like to use the cURL library to do this. Can you help me write a sample code to get me started to post my variables to the api.instagram.com/oauth/access_token? Sorry im new to this thank you

Comment: there are a pretty much examples of how to post using [`curl`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php), this is a pretty simple [example](http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php#83937). however, it's recommended to follow the api instructions;